# Modulus on Combinatorials

Tags: java, combinatorics, modulus

Suppose a number n and we have to find sum of all combinatorials of n i.e. nC0+nC1+nC2+...+ nCn. 
As result can be large so final answer should be sum%D (D=10^9+7).

Approach I used is-

```
long sum=0;
long combination=1;
for(int i=1;i<=n;i++){
   combination=((combination*(n-i+1))/i)%D;
   sum=(sum+combination)%D;
}
```

But this is not working.

Real [Problem statement](http://practice.geeksforgeeks.org/problems/count-even-length/0) and [code](http://ide.geeksforgeeks.org/6FJA1m).Code is giving correct output till n=20.

Answer (score 0):

You're supposed to mod the final output, not along every step of the way.
Also the numbers get very large so use BigInteger instead of long.

Here is my solution
http://ide.geeksforgeeks.org/Ew3Epn

Using the formula (2*n)!/(n!)^2
found here -> https://oeis.org/A000984